# Does each inductive definition represent new inference rules?

Tags: type-theory

This is the one thing that I understand the least about formal type theory. For example, in HoTT, the book is filled with casual (higher or not) inductive definitions (lists, quotients, the real numbers). In the formalizations at the end, however, only a few of these actually get inference rules - products, coproducts, the empty and unit types, the natural numbers, and the identity type. They do say things like "other inductively defined types follow the same general scheme" under the definition of $\mathbb{N}$, which leads me to believe that every time an inductive definition is given in type theory, it entails the addition of new inference rules.

To me, this seems impractical and kind of ugly in comparison to set theory, where there are a fixed number of logical inference rules and axioms which can be combined to define complicated constructions directly.

Am I misunderstanding the nature of inductive types? I can imagine that the existence of certain classes of inductive types could be proven in some concrete model of type theory, but I haven't seen something like that in a direct formalism, and I can't imagine what it would look like.

Comment: (In my personal opinion) there is nothing ugly about being able to write down the actual inductive type you want directly, instead of having to encode it in various (often convoluted) ways like in set theory. Same goes for having direct coinductive definitions in type theory, even though they can usually be encoded via inductive types and Π.

Comment: @DanDoel I can accept that for sure. My only qualm is that those types are part of the foundations instead of being derived from the foundations, so it takes away from the percieved simplicity of being able to write down a fixed list of all your rules and axioms on a single page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In much the same way that in ZFC [comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification) is actually an axiom *schema* (in the sense that it's multiple axioms in a trenchcoat, one instance for each formula $\varphi$), one common way to work with inductive types is via [$W$-types](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/W-type). These are multiple introduction/elimination/computation in a trenchcoat, with roughly one instance for each inductive type. For instance, lists, natural numbers, trees, etc. are all instances of the "rule schema" for $W$-types. So in exactly the same way that comprehension gives a *uniform* way of defining *infinitely many* axioms, $W$-types gives a *uniform* way of defining *infinitely many* inductive types! See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_type#W-_and_M-types).

This is also helpful for semantics, since $W$-types are semantically interpreted as [initial algebras](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/initial+algebra+of+an+endofunctor#semantics_for_inductive_types) for (polynomial) endofunctors, and often it's easy to check that a given category always has such initial algebras (and thus model all $W$-types). See [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/inductive+type#CategoricalSemantics) for instance.

This story becomes more complicated in intentional type theories (such as HoTT), but morally the same idea works. See Awodey, Gambino, and Sojakova's [*Inductive Types in Homotopy Type Theory*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.3898.pdf) for more.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: That makes sense. Is there a similar way in which higher inductive types from HoTT (for like the real numbers or quotients, or spaces for synthetic homotopy theory) can also be axiomatized "all at once" like W-types? If not, is there any research about this you could point me towards?

Comment: Hm... I don't know of one, but I'm not an expert in HITs. If you're only interested in non-recursive HITs (like the circle, torus, etc.) then you can add (homotopy) pushouts as an axiom and build everything else from that. Iirc recursive HITs (like propositional truncation) are a bit more complicated, but people must know something since they've been [implmented in cubical agda](https://www.cse.chalmers.se/~abela/icfp19.pdf), as well as LEAN, etc.

Comment: As of 2018, though, "There is no uniformly accepted scheme of which HITs
are allowed, and the semantics of HITs is a topic of current research." See chapter 3 of [Flooris van Doorn's thesis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.10690.pdf) both for the quote, and for more information about this. There have been at least some progress since 2018, though. For instance, we now have semantics for a wide range of uniformly defined HITs. See Lumsdaine and Shulman's ["Semantics of Higher Inductive Types"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.07088.pdf).

Comment: Thank you! This is very interesting and helpful.